# Should I install ubuntu 12.04 or 13.04?

Tags: 12.04, 13.04

Recently I have migrated from ubuntu 13.04 64 bits to 32 bits in my laptop because I was getting some trouble with some software. Meanwhile, I have faced another problems with compatibility, with guitar pro 6 that I can't open after installing ( and I can made it work on ubuntu 12.04 in a virtual machine).
Should I downgrade to ubuntu 12.04? Are there more programs available for ubuntu 12.04 than for 13.04?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

12.04 is a [long term release](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS), supported for five years. In theory, this is the version that developers *should* be targeting if they want their software to just-work™.

Sticking with the LTS sounds like a sensible idea in your case. I would suggest testing a LiveCD before you next upgrade (and perhaps wait for the next LTS - 14.04).

Comment: 13.04 is supported for 9 months only... and hence you can understand the problem associated.